# How to change the background of multiple activities at the same time?

Tags: android

I am developing an app with 3 activities. Every activity has the same background. I want to enable the users to change the background of all the three activities. So i used a AlertDialog to provide the user several choices. When the user click the items on the Dialog, the background will be changed.

I have tried two ways of implementing this function above:

1) use the Android:theme in AndroidManifest.XML. This really worked. But the bad thing was that all the View in the application will extend the theme. I made the background of unrelated views null. But i can not remove extended theme in the Dialog. This made my dialog very ugly.

2) I applied 'style' in the layout xml of the three activity. But the problem is that i can not modify the background attribute in the style programmatically.

Does someone have some idea to deal with this problem? thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of options, but here are 2 that I can think of:

1. Create a custom Dialog and override the method that sets the theme to cancel the change of the new theme.
2. Keep a preference in the application preferences that states the background image selected, then set the background of the main layout view of each activity when the activity is started.

Comment: Hi John, your solutions are very helpful, especially the second one. For your first suggestion, i also thought about that before, but it's a lot of coding because i have several Dialogs in the application. So i will try the second one.

Comment: @Fly:  If you create your own extended AlertDialog class (say, MyAlertDialog), you would only need to rename the instances of each dialog.  I do think that the second method would be easier though, so good luck.  Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: @John plz help i am also facing the same issue of applying the background image to all the other activities based on user selection any links on that plz ...