# Changing the background image based on user selection which applies to entire application

Tags: android, image, background

Guys i am new to android, In my application the user is provided the option to change the background image, suppose the user selects the a image and clicks on apply it should not only apply to that activity but it should also apply to other activities.

how to acheive this can we do it with shared preferences

Comment: i have tried doing with shared preferences but still not working

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6699893/how-to-change-the-background-of-multiple-activities-at-the-same-time please check this

Comment: yeah concept is ok...I am sure you missing something in ur code.Double check ur code.

Answer (score 0):

Use theme for this purpose, its best according to your question,

see:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

create a theme, and dont set background to any activity just let it to default. Apply the same theme to all activities, and on selection of image change attribute background to new image.

Set Background like this:

```
<color name="custom_theme_color">#b0b0ff</color>
<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/custom_theme_color</item>
</style>
```

Comment: so u mean i need to create a style first

Comment: suppose i have style like this <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>  then what next

Comment: i have added the above code into res/values/styles.xml is it fine?

Comment: now on selection of an image change attribute by method http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/Resources.Theme.html#applyStyle%28int,%20boolean%29

Comment: but how will it be applied to other activity

Comment: coz theme is being set to all activity